# Strange x87 result: sin(1)-sin(1)=1.73472e-18

Tags: floating-point, x87

While debugging some code, I came across x87 behavior that I don't understand.
Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double test1(double x,double y)
{
   __asm {
        fld x
        fsin
        fld y
        fsin
        fsubp st(1),st(0)
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << test1( 1, 1)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Everything is fine here, the output is `0`. Now we slightly modify the `test` function so that the intermediate result is stored in memory:

```
double test2(double x,double y)
{
    double tmp;
   __asm {
        fld x
        fsin
        fld y
        fsin
        fstp tmp
        fld tmp
        fsubp st(1),st(0)
   }
}
```

Now the output is `1.78893e-18`. This result can be explained by rounding the intermediate value stored in memory. But I don’t understand why the result is non-zero even if the precision of x87 floating-point calculations is set to double or single and regardless of rounding mode:

```
double test3(double x,double y)
{
        // Double precision, 
        // round toward zero
    unsigned short cw = 0xe7f;
    double tmp;
    __asm {
        fldcw cw
        fld x
        fsin
        fld y
        fsin
        fstp tmp
        fld tmp
        fsubp st(1),st(0)
   }
}
```

The `fsubp` instruction should consider the precision mode and ignore unnecessary bits, right? Why, then, is the result non-zero in any rounding mode? After all, in at least one of the rounding modes, rounded bits must match?

Comment: I don't think `fsubp` will round its *inputs* to match the current precision; only the output. And `fsin` isn't affected by the control word precision.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23965243/270986

Answer (score 0):

In x87, numbers are stored in `long double`. Casting to `double` by `fstp` lose some precision.